# What is meant by Hydrogen dilution in Plasma?

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, radiation, plasma-physics

I was going through the paper of methanol masers and it says that for a strong maser the geometrical dilution factor of HII emission should have low values. What is the meaning geometrical dilution factor? Can you please explain?

Comment: Have you tried looking at [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_of_precision_(GPS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_of_precision_(GPS)) and [http://www.hindawi.com/journals/jam/2013/953048/](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/jam/2013/953048/)?

Answer (score 1):

> Dilution of precision (DOP), or geometric dilution of precision (GDOP), is a term used in satellite navigation and geomatics engineering to specify the additional multiplicative effect of navigation satellite geometry on positional measurement precision.

So a simple answer is that it's effect of navigation satellite geometry for precisely measuring your position. Is this really a physics question?

Comment: Can you please add the source for that quotation? :)